# How to merge 2 tabs into 1 result? (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've 2 tabs, it names Class A and Class B, like this :

[image]
[image]

And my question is How to merge this data into 1 result with query? And I want the result is just like this:

[image]

For the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmUMlprKNh1r6O81KuLtaNOQchx5sYn_ihirkG9tzWk/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY('Class A'!A3:A, "select 'Class A',A");
 QUERY('Class B'!A3:A, "select 'Class B',A")}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT({
 IF('Class A'!A3:A="",,'Class A'!A1&"♦"&'Class A'!A3:A);
 IF('Class B'!A3:A="",,'Class B'!A1&"♦"&'Class B'!A3:A)}, "♦"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can I get the value `Class A` or `Class B` from A1 and not hard coded like that? Thanks again